# aiohttp BaseConnector _acquired vs _conns

Tags: aiohttp

I see internally connections (<aiohttp.client_proto.ResponseHandler objects) are stored in:  `_conns` and `_acquired`
What is the difference between those?

context: I try to investigate why  connections hang on..
when limit for TCPConnector is set, lets say to **10**,
with `lsof` I see like **70** of them (ESTABLISHED)
The number drops after sth like 20min..

ps: I use: session.get(url, `ssl=False`)

Comment: ps.: [Gracefull shutdown trick](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#graceful-shutdown) seems not related here, as my the ClientSession does not close for 24h -- waits for urls through queue

Comment: >... the ClientSession does not close for 24h ..

seems, I was wrong, async loop runs for 24h, but session usually crawls 50k urls, and closes in ~1h...